# Can i convert from table to list in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, list

Is there an easy way to convert all my table data to a list? somthing like:

DbContext.Users.tolist();

Comment: Write `ToList()` and t ought to work. But I'm suspecting that's not your actual question. Be more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using (YourContext context = new YourContext())
{
    var usersList = context.Users.ToList();
}
```

Make sure to add

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I am using asp.net5 and there the function is not present